# Angular 2: Route to default on refresh

Tags: angular

I wonder if it is possible to tell Angular 2 app to redirect to default route (**localhost:8080/**) on page refresh.

See example:

```
 localhost:8080/#/home    ---refresh action--->     localhost:8080/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to turn off `initialNavigation`, where you import the router module:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES, {initialNavigation: false})
```

And then in some constructor of a root service or wherever you would like it inject the router and navigate to `/`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code, it will always redirect to 'default' route

```
history.pushState(null, null, '/');
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
    history.pushState(null, null, '/');
});
```